# How to remove directories in the correct order so that empty ones are removed?

Tags: shell-script, directory, rm

I have a list of files & directories in a file in some order, and I want to write  a script that removes them.

*Directories are **only** supposed to be removed if all of their descendents will also be removed.*
(Put another way, they should only be removed if they'd be empty after the script has run many times.)

I'd really prefer to do this in 1 pass.
But doing this in 1 pass seems  to require doing things in a correct order (post-order traversal).

I assume this is a known problem... how do people generally solve it in a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

> I assume this is a known problem... how do people generally solve it in a shell script?

They pass the list of files and directories to `sort -r`.

If you are getting the list of files and directories from `find`, you can also use the `-depth` option to ensure post-order traversal.

Answer (score 0):

You could try ordering the files by the number of slashes in it ( descending ) , this way you should solve the ordering problem.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out independently.

It can be done with `awk`. Note that this solution does **not** tolerate newlines in the file name.

```
awk -- '{a=$$0;b=$$0;print(gsub("/","/",a)-sub(/\/$$/,"aaa",b),$$0)}' INPUT_FILE.txt \
    |  "$(call Q2,/usr/bin/sort)" -k1,1nr \
    |  cut -d " " -f 2-
```

And while I'm here -- the lines can be de-duplicated through the following:

```
awk -- '{pos[$$0] = NR} END { for(key in pos) reverse[pos[key]] = key; for(nr=1;nr<=NR;nr++) if(nr in reverse) print reverse[nr] }' INPUT_FILE.txt
```

Note that de-duplication is **critical** to prevent exponential time blow-up if you end up recursing.